# How to get JSON from an HBase record in Python?

Tags: python, rest, hbase

I have a Python dict object `row` which contains some bytes objects.

So when I try doing
`json.dumps(row, indent = 4)`

I get this error

`TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable`

Now my problem is that this `row` object comes from HBase so I have no much control over it.

I am using this library

https://pypi.org/project/hbase-rest-py/

which connects to the HBase REST API and returns to me this `row` dict object.

It is JSON-like but contains bytes objects.

**So how do I pretty print it or convert it to JSON, provided that it's a dictionary but this dictionary contains some bytes objects?!**

If I just print it (with Python's built-in print function), I get this:

`{'row': [{'key': b'B70DA612B08299967EB536F9EAF88CB4_20221115_685611_DESKTOP_SEARCH_SEARCH', 'cell': [{'column': b'p:clk', 'timestamp': 1668687955736, '$': b'2'}, {'column': b'p:con1', 'timestamp': 1668687955736, '$': b'0.0000'}, {'column': b'p:cst', 'timestamp': 1668687955736, '$': b'7140000.000000'}, {'column': b'p:cwm', 'timestamp': 1668687955736, '$': b'16.604651'}, {'column': b'p:eis', 'timestamp': 1668687955736, '$': b'42.86%'}, {'column': b'p:imp', 'timestamp': 1668687955736, '$': b'25'}, {'column': b'p:se', 'timestamp': 1668687955736, '$': b'2'}, {'column': b'p:sis', 'timestamp': 1668687955736, '$': b'13.59%'}, {'column': b'p:sisb', 'timestamp': 1668687955736, '$': b'9.78%'}, {'column': b'p:sisr', 'timestamp': 1668687955736, '$': b'76.63%'}]}]}`

But this is not easy to read.

**Also, most importantly, how do I get valid JSON from this dictionary object?**

These b prefixes which I have there make this invalid JSON.

I tried using `pprint.PrettyPrinter`, the output from it looks ugly too. And also, it breaks my key into two, not sure why.

```
{   'row': [   {   'cell': [   {   '$': b'2',
                                   'column': b'p:clk',
                                   'timestamp': 1668766822651},
                               {   '$': b'0.0000',
                                   'column': b'p:con1',
                                   'timestamp': 1668766822651},
                               {   '$': b'7140000.000000',
                                   'column': b'p:cst',
                                   'timestamp': 1668766822651},
                               {   '$': b'16.604651',
                                   'column': b'p:cwm',
                                   'timestamp': 1668766822651},
                               {   '$': b'42.86%',
                                   'column': b'p:eis',
                                   'timestamp': 1668766822651},
                               {   '$': b'25',
                                   'column': b'p:imp',
                                   'timestamp': 1668766822651},
                               {   '$': b'2',
                                   'column': b'p:se',
                                   'timestamp': 1668766822651},
                               {   '$': b'13.59%',
                                   'column': b'p:sis',
                                   'timestamp': 1668766822651},
                               {   '$': b'9.78%',
                                   'column': b'p:sisb',
                                   'timestamp': 1668766822651},
                               {   '$': b'76.63%',
                                   'column': b'p:sisr',
                                   'timestamp': 1668766822651}],
                   'key': b'B70DA612B08299967EB536F9EAF88CB4_20221115_685611'
                          b'_DESKTOP_SEARCH_SEARCH'}]}
```

**Do I need to traverse this object and convert each binary string into a normal string?! I am hoping to avoid that. Isn't there an easier way?**

Comment: The Python json docs show you how to deal with encoding custom types. Use the `indent` parameter of `dumps` to pretty print it

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper I am not sure where to look even (Python is not my main language). I thought it would be something simple to convert this dict object to JSON. But so far I am unable to do it.

Comment: I'm on my phone, can't be of much help :D But Python has official docs for its built in libs like json. It should mention how to add a fallback function for types it can't convert, or how to make and use your custom Encoder class

Comment: The main problem is that `bytes` have no encoding, so they can't be directly written to your JSON file without showing up as binary garbage and control characters. So you probably want to encode them. Your question is also a duplicate, there's many answers for "how to write bytes to json" on SO. You do not need to traverse it. your fallback function is called for you whenever json fails to encode something

Comment: Here this should help: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder override the `default` method to deal with types it can't encode

Comment: Can you try .decode('utf-8') for each of the byte-encoded values? Since it appears that in the return dict the keys are not bytes, but values are, maybe you can get dict.values() and then work on them?